# How to build Consumer Widget of Provider Package Specifically for method of Class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I want to use Consumer Widget of Provider Package in such Way that it will only run when a specific method of Class run or notifyListeners() call.

Like Here is a class

```
Class Example with ChangeNotifier{
void exampleMethod(){
//....Do SomeThing
notifyListeners();
  }

void exampleOneMethod(){
//....Do SomeThing
notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

So when I call Consumer in Some Widget Like This:

```
  Consumer<Example>(builder:(_,ex,__)=>SomeWidget(
   ex.exampleOneMethod();
      )
```

Soo Consumer Widget will Only Rebuild if exampleOneMethod run and not on other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The Consumer Widget should be rebuild if some other methods call the `notifyListeners()` I think that for your purpose you should structure the methods in a different way, or use `Provider.of<Example>(context, listen: false).exampleOneMethod()` the `listend: false` should ensure you that it will not rebuild if someone call notify

Comment: Yes that is the way but then it will rebuilt the whole Stateless/Statefull widget when that method call notifyListeners(). But I want to only rebuild specific part of whole Stateless/Statefull widget.

Comment: Maybe you could try to put the Consumer deeper in the tree call, what is your usage of the exampleOneMethod?